# Aws Transribe unable to start_transcription_job without LanguageCode in boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cdk, amazon-transcribe

I have an audio file in `S3`.

I don't know the language of the audio file. So I need to use `IdentifyLanguage` for `start_transcription_job()`.

`LanguageCode` will be blank since I don't know the language of the audio file.

**Envirionment**

Using
Python 3.8 runtime,
boto3 version `1.16.5` ,
botocore version: `1.19.5`,
no Lambda Layer.

**Here is my code for the Transcribe job:**

```
mediaFileUri = 's3://'+ bucket_name+'/'+prefixKey

transcribe_client = boto3.client('transcribe')

response = transcribe_client.start_transcription_job(
    TranscriptionJobName="abc",
    IdentifyLanguage=True,
    Media={
        'MediaFileUri':mediaFileUri
    },
)
```

**Then I get this error:**

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nMissing required parameter in input: \"LanguageCode\"\nUnknown parameter in input: \"IdentifyLanguage\", must be one of: TranscriptionJobName, LanguageCode, MediaSampleRateHertz, MediaFormat, Media, OutputBucketName, OutputEncryptionKMSKeyId, Settings, ModelSettings, JobExecutionSettings, ContentRedaction",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 27, in TranscribeSoundToWordHandler\n    response = response = transcribe_client.start_transcription_job(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 316, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 607, in _make_api_call\n    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 655, in _convert_to_request_dict\n    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py\", line 297, in serialize_to_request\n    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())\n"
  ]
}
```

With this error, means that I must specify the `LanguageCode` and `IdentifyLanguage` is an invalid parameter.

100% sure the audio file exist in S3. But without `LanguageCode` it don't work, and `IdentifyLanguage` parameter is unknown parameter

**I using SAM application to test locally using this command:**

```
sam local invoke MyHandler -e lambda\TheDirectory\event.json
```

And I `cdk deploy`, and check in Aws Lambda Console as well, tested it the same `events.json`, but still getting the same error

This I think is Lambda Execution environment, I didn't use any Lambda Layer.

**I look at this docs from Aws Transcribe:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/API_StartTranscriptionJob.html

and this docs of `boto3`:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/transcribe.html#TranscribeService.Client.start_transcription_job

Clearly state that `LanguageCode` is not required and `IdentifyLanguage` is a valid parameter.

So what I missing out? Any idea on this? What should I do?

**Update:**

I keep searching and asked couple person online, I think I should build the function container 1st to let SAM package the boto3 into the container.

So what I do is, `cdk synth` a template file:

```
cdk synth --no-staging > template.yaml
```

Then:

```
sam build --use-container
sam local invoke MyHandler78A95900 -e lambda\TheDirectory\event.json
```

But still, I get the same error, but post the stack trace as well

```
[ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in input: "LanguageCode"
Unknown parameter in input: "IdentifyLanguage", must be one of: TranscriptionJobName, LanguageCode, MediaSampleRateHertz, MediaFormat, Media, OutputBucketName, OutputEncryptionKMSKeyId, Settings, JobExecutionSettings, ContentRedaction
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 27, in TranscribeSoundToWordHandler
    response = response = transcribe_client.start_transcription_job(
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 607, in _make_api_call
    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 655, in _convert_to_request_dict
    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py", line 297, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
```

Really no clue what I doing wrong here. I also report a [github issue here](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2649), but seem like cant reproduce the issue.

**Main Question/Problem:**

Unable to `start_transription_job`

1. without `LanguageCode`
2. with `IdentifyLanguage=True`

What possible reason cause this, and how can I solve this problem(Dont know the languange of the audio file, I want to identify language of audio file without given the LanguageCode) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up I notice this is because my packaged lambda function isn’t being uploaded for some reason. Here is how I solved it after getting help from couple of people.

**First modify CDK stack which define my lambda function like this:**

```
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_lambda as lambda_,
    core
)

from aws_cdk.aws_lambda_python import PythonFunction

class MyCdkStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        # define lambda 
        my_lambda = PythonFunction(
            self, 'MyHandler',
            entry='lambda/MyHandler',
            index='app.py',
            runtime=lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
            handler='MyHandler', 
            timeout=core.Duration.seconds(10)
        )
```

This will use [aws-lambda-python module](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-lambda-python-readme.html) ,it will handle installing all required modules into the docker.

**Next, cdk synth a template file**

```
cdk synth --no-staging > template.yaml
```

At this point, it will bundling all the stuff inside `entry` path which define in `PythonFunction` and install all the necessary dependencies defined in `requirements.txt` inside that `entry` path.

**Next, build the docker container**

```
$ sam build --use-container
```

Make sure `template.yaml` file in root directory. This will build a docker container, and the artifact will build inside `.aws-sam/build` directory in my root directory.

**Last step, invoke the function using sam:**

```
sam local invoke MyHandler78A95900 -e path\to\event.json
```

Now finally successfully call `start_transcription_job` as stated in my question above without any error.

**In Conclusion:**

1. At the very beginning I only `pip install boto3`, this only will
   install the `boto3` in my local system.
2. Then, I `sam local invoke` without build the container 1st by `sam build --use-container`
3. Lastly, I have `sam build` at last, but in that point, I didn't
   bundle what defined inside `requirements.txt` into the
   `.aws-sam/build`, therefore need to use [aws-lambda-python
   module](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-lambda-python-readme.html) as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you are using the latest boto3 version.

```
boto3.__version__  
'1.16.5'
```

I tried it and it works.

```
import boto3

transcribe = boto3.client('transcribe')
response = transcribe.start_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName='Test-20201-27',IdentifyLanguage=True,Media={'MediaFileUri':'s3://BucketName/DemoData/Object.mp4'})

print(response)
{
    "TranscriptionJob": {
        "TranscriptionJobName": "Test-20201-27",
        "TranscriptionJobStatus": "IN_PROGRESS",
        "Media": {
            "MediaFileUri": "s3://BucketName/DemoData/Object.mp4"
        },
        "StartTime": "datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 15, 41, 2, 599000, tzinfo=tzlocal())",
        "CreationTime": "datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 15, 41, 2, 565000, tzinfo=tzlocal())",
        "IdentifyLanguage": "True"
    },
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "RequestId": "9e4f94a4-20e4-4ca0-9c6e-e21a8934084b",
        "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
        "HTTPHeaders": {
            "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
            "date": "Tue, 27 Oct 2020 14:41:02 GMT",
            "x-amzn-requestid": "9e4f94a4-20e4-4ca0-9c6e-e21a8934084b",
            "content-length": "268",
            "connection": "keep-alive"
        },
        "RetryAttempts": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey sir, just checked that the version is `Version: 1.16.5` is the same.. and I actually call `start_transription_job` just like you are. But I still get the error above.

Comment: Try to include `boto3` in requirements.txt and then run `sam build --use-container ` followed by `sam local invoke -e events/event.json`