# AWS Transcribe - JS docs say "LanguageCode" is optional, but code says its required?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs, amazon-transcribe

I'm playing with `aws-sdk` (version 2.1063.0) in NodeJs and the AWS Transcribe service. I'm planning to upload audio files with unknown language codes, and have AWS Transcribe detect the language and then transcribe the text.

However, the docs for AWS Transcribe and `startTranscriptionJob` shows that `LanguageCode` isn't required: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/API_StartTranscriptionJob.html

Yet when i run my code, i see the error `MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'LanguageCode' in params`

Even in the AWS Transcribe web portal, i'm able to upload audio files with "Automatic Language Detection" as an option. I'd like to do the same programmatically.

[image]

Does anyone have suggestions? I saw [Aws Transribe unable to start_transcription_job without LanguageCode in boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64555481/aws-transribe-unable-to-start-transcription-job-without-languagecode-in-boto3), but wasn't able to apply it to my javascript/node code

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `"IdentifyLanguage": true` in `--identify-language`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/cli/latest/reference/transcribe/start-transcription-job.html

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm stumped on `"UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'IdentifyLanguage'"`, this further adds to my confusion since it's listed in the docs. I got the same when i have the key 'OutputKey' as well. `aws-sdk` version is `2.1063.0` which is pretty recent. Any thoughts?